# consul dnsmasq and tls

Tags: ssl, dnsmasq, consul

I have a 3 node consul cluster and setup dnsmasq as described here: http://www.morethanseven.net/2014/04/25/consul/

Everything was working and I was able to query dns for a service using dig or nslookup. 
I enabled tls and I am no longer able to query dns. Do I need to configure dnsmasq to use an SSL certificate?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the ip address consul was binding to so it was no longer listening on 127.0.0.1. I had to change the file `/etc/dnsmasq.d/10-consul` and update the ip address